# Hardness of iterated squaring in Paillier group

Tags: factoring, complexity, paillier, hardness-assumptions

The (computational) problem of *iterated squaring* (IS) in the RSA group is defined as follows, where $\leftarrow$ denotes sampling uniformly at random:

> Input: $(N,x,T)$, where $N$ is the RSA modulus, $x\leftarrow\mathbb{Z}_N^*$, and $T\in\mathbb{N}$ is the time parameter
>
> Solution: $x^{2^T}\bmod{N}$.

This problem can be traced back to [C+] and used by [RSW] for constructing time-lock puzzles. More recently, it has been used to build [verifiable delay functions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/601) [P,W]. It is not hard to see that the problem is at most as hard as factoring $N$. My question concerns the analogous problem in the [Paillier group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem) (ISP, for short), as used in [LM] and defined as follows*:

> Input: $(N,x,T)$, where $N$ is the RSA modulus, $x=v^N\bmod{N^2}$ for $v\leftarrow\mathbb{Z}_N^*$  and, $T\in\mathbb{N}$ is the time parameter
>
> Solution: $x^{2^T}\bmod{N^2}$.

**Question: Is the hardness of these problems related? Are these problems  reducible to one another?**

*Why should they be related?* Intuitively speaking, the RSA group is embedded in the Paillier group and constitutes its component of unknown order (which is necessary for iterated squaring to be hard). More formally:
$$(\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^*,\times)\cong (\mathbb{Z}_N^*,\times)\times(\mathbb{Z}_N,+),$$
and since iterated squaring in the $(\mathbb{Z}_N,+)$ component is easy (as it is a group of known order), one could conjecture that hardness of solving ISP boils down to solving IS.

However, I could not find a reduction in either direction. For instance, to reduce IS to ISP one could try the canonical embedding of $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^*$ defined as
$$x\bmod{N}\mapsto x^N\bmod{N}^2,$$
but this runs into the RSA problem when trying to map the solution back. In the other direction, one could try the canonical projection defined as
$$x\bmod{N^2}\mapsto x\bmod{N},$$
but it is now not possible to lift the solution back to $\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^*$. Any ideas?

*Another way to define it would be as follows:

> Input: $(N,x,T)$, where $N$ is the RSA modulus, $x\leftarrow\mathbb{Z}_{N^2}^*$, and $T\in\mathbb{N}$ is the time parameter
>
> Solution: $x^{2^T}\bmod{N^2}$.

But it seems less natural than the formulation above.

*References.*

[C+]: Cai et al, [Towards uncheatable benchmarks](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/336546), CCC'93 (behind a paywall unfortunately)

[LM]: Lai and Malavolta [Homomorphic Time-Lock Puzzles and Applications](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/635), Crypto'19

[P]: Pietzak, [Simple verifiable delay functions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/627), ITCS'19

[RSW]: Rivest, Shamir and Wagner, [Time-lock puzzles and timed-release crypto](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/RSW96.pdf), MIT Report

[W]: Wesolwski, [Efficient verifiable delay functions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/623), Eurocrypt'19

Comment: Either you basically gave the answer, or the following has a flaw.
Write $Z_{N^2}$ elements as $x_0 (1+N)^{x_1} \equiv x_0 + x_0 x_1 N$,
the map $Z_{N^2} \to Z_N$ amounts to setting $x_1 = 0$.
Suppose $y_0 \equiv x_0^t \; (N)$ (say for $t = 2^T$).
To compute a compatible $y_1$ for a $Z_{N^2}$ representative, solve $y_0 + y_0 y_1 N \equiv x_0^t + t x_0 x_1 N$, i.e. let $y_1 N\equiv t x_0^{-t} x_0 x_1 N\mod N^2$.
If $x_0$ is not invertible, we factor $N$ and can trivially solve.
That gives you $(y_0, y_1)$ which is the $t$-th power of $(x_0, x_1)$.
Any mistake? (Computing $y_1$ is fast!?)

Comment: Not sure I follow. As per the first formulation of the problem, the $\mathbb{Z}_N$ component (which you call $(1+N)^{x_1}$) is already set to $1$. Could you rephrase your answer with that in mind? (This should be a simpler task as I feel you are trying to show that even the second formulation reduces to IS.)

Comment: I missed the power $N$ for the canonical embedding... what I described doesn't work. Perhaps letting $t=2^T N$ helps, although it changes the question? (Perhaps I'm overlooking something again.)